# How to add Firebase Auth to a .xcworkspace with Firebase already added

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently started working on a Firebase project. When I originally created it, I only had

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database’
```

in my Podfile. Now I added the line     `pod 'Firebase/Auth’` to the project so I can sign users in. When I try to make a sign in VC, I can't access any of the Auth code even when I import `FirebaseAuth` above the class. Any ideas on how to refresh the Podfile so I can use the Auth code?

Comment: Have you installed the pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building your code first and then try using it again. If that is not working, try cleaning your project and doing:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```